# Comparing today's date against future dates in a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

# Read csv file
df=pd.read_csv("data.csv", engine="python", header=None)

# Add column header names
df.columns=["EmployeeID", "LastName", "FirstName", "DOB", "Email", "Salary", "DOH", "TermDate"]

# Determine which Dates of Hire are earlier than today's date
df0 = df.loc[df["DOH"] > (dt.datetime.today().strftime('%m/%d/%Y')), ["EmployeeID", "LastName", "FirstName", "DOH"]]

# Print dataframe output to separate worksheet within one Excel file
with pd.ExcelWriter("ErrorOutput.xlsx") as writer:
    df0.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Incorrect DOH", index=False)
```

I'm vetting CSV files for incorrect Dates of Hire (DOH) by simply comparing them to today's date. I want the records with future DOH's to show as errant records in the Excel file.

When I run the code, I get dates in records that are prior to today's date which is the opposite of what I want. I'm guessing my `dt.datetime.today().strftime('%m/%d/%Y')` line is the issue. The file date format is MM/DD/YYYY.

Comment: `'%m/%d/%Y'` should be the correct format spec for a MM/DD/YYYY data. If your getting the records *prior* to the date, why not try changing the conditional from `>` to `<=`, e.g.: `df.loc[df["DOH"] <= (dt.datetime.today() ...` to see what happens?

Comment: I don't know how `pandas`'s magic expressions work, but have you tried it without calling `strftime`?  Formatting the current date as a string might be causing it to do a string comparison instead of a date/time comparison.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that checking if strings are greater than another string seems to be causing problems. I wrote a little script that compares today's date with older dates and a date from next month, but all of them appear to evaluate to false when I compare them. Perhaps you can convert the dates to their integer values since epoch or format the dates into a string without slashes and convert them to integers. The snippet below shows the string comparison failing but working if I format without slashes and cast to ints.

```
import datetime as dt

april_date = "4/20/2023"
last_year_date = "10/30/2022"
next_month = "6/16/2023"

today = dt.datetime.today().strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

print("Today: ", today)
print("Next month: ", next_month, today > next_month)
print("April Date: ", april_date, today > april_date)
print("Last Year Date: ", last_year_date, today > last_year_date)

#Formatting the dates without slashes and converting them to ints yields the correct comparison result

today = int(dt.datetime.today().strftime('%m%d%Y'))
next_month = int("06162023")
april_date = int("04202023")

print("Next month int: ", next_month, today > next_month)
print("April Date int: ", april_date, today > april_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forgot to parse the `DOH` as a date. Also, no need for external *datetime* modules :

```
headers = [
    "EmployeeID", "LastName", "FirstName",
    "DOB", "Email", "Salary", "DOH", "TermDate"
]

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", header=None, names=headers, parse_dates=["DOH"])

df0 = df.loc[df["DOH"] > pd.Timestamp("now"),
             ["EmployeeID", "LastName", "FirstName", "DOH"]]

with pd.ExcelWriter("ErrorOutput.xlsx") as writer:
    df0.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Incorrect DOH", index=False)
```